# Parallax and Pin collapse modes not working in Collapsing Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, scroll, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

This is my code of my test project:-
Main Activity

```
 package com.invento.defcomm.collapsingtoolbarlayout;

import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
public static final int COLLAPSE_MODE_PARALLAX=2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    collapsingToolbarLayout= (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collpasing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("TEST COLLAPSING TOOLBAR");
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.expandedTitleColor));
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

activity main xml file:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collpasing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="@color/contentscrim"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/index"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

color xml file:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="contentscrim">#846735</color>
   <color name="expandedTitleColor">#ffffff</color>
   </resources>
```

style xml file:-

```
 <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

The problem is that the activity loads up fine. There is no error in there. But the Parallax scroll effect is not working. Is there something I 'm missing? Please point it out.

Comment: Somebody please help!!!!

Comment: I 'am in the middle of a project please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I defined a NestedScrollView inside my activity, Now it works fine.
Since the AppBarLayout detects the scroll gesture from NestedScrollView, it then makes the necessary changes in the CollapsingToolBar .

Answer (score 0):

The content needs to be in a Nested Scroll View:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:background="?colorPrimary">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/eclairs"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/arrow_left" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/cupcake_ipsum"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```